# More than one use case in a single sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I want to create a very basic sequence diagram for the first iteration of my app. I have a database of exercises, and I have a use case for creating, another for editing, and another for deleting an exercise. They are all very simple, and use the same elements and actors, like User, DAO, and Database. What I want to do is to create a single SD, that begins with the user asking to create an exercise, followed by the user asking to edit that exercise, and then asking to delete it. My question is: is this considered correct in a sequence diagram? I don't want to create 3 SDs almost identical to one another, and this seems like a simple way to represent all the information, but I don't know if this is correct by UML standards. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a standards conformance point of view, there is nothing in the UML standard, that imposes a relationship between your use case models and sequence diagramme models. So, no matter how many use cases you want to reflect in a sequence diagramme, it would be neither "correct" nor "incorrect".

From a personal point of view : What you are asking about is a question of modeling style, not conformity. As long as the people who are reading your models understand them, you can do whatever you want. So, something like this would be perfectly fine :

[image]

Comment: From a standards conformance point of view, your sequence diagram is not valid. UML does not allow a lifeline to be partially dashed. Comments like 'some time later' should be written inside a note symbol. Return arrows should be dashed. For a readability point of view, the diagram is perfectly fine.

Comment: Absolutely correct @www.admiraalit.nl, I was a bit sloppy with the diagramme. I have updated it. I hope it's better now !

Comment: Thanks, I'm still very new to this and I'm still not very sure about which things are valid and which are not in a UML diagram, but, from what I've seen, most things you'd want to do to simplify diagrams are valid as long as they're understandable for others

Comment: I assume you use Rational (or some descendant of it). Always wonder why they survive with those arrows being half way between filled and not filled. Whale spears ;-)